# Measuring length of network reached within specific search tolerance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

The purpose of this analysis is to make a measure of how well developed the street network is in different areas of a given city. The result I'm looking for is to give different parts of the network different shades of colour, to indicate which areas have the most developed pedestrian Networks. This Id think could be further developed into a polygon layer (areas of the city With best road network) for overlay analysis.

I have a good pedestrian network, but don't know how to do this analysis. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a service area? This outputs polygons based on the input distances you specify, like a buffer but along the network. 
This link (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) explains how to use the tool. 
I'm currently using it to create walk isochrones - in the analysis settings i've specified that I want breaks at 400, 800 and 1200m. [analysis settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1lMe.png) and the result is: [image: polygons]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this answer? Perhaps with pictures, links and examples? At the moment, I think it could be improved with more detail.